# Alternative/Equivalent of ReadAsAsync<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient

I upgraded from .net framework 4 to 4.6.

```
  public static async Task<bool> SignIn(string userName, string password)
        {
            var user = new { UserName = userName, Password = password };
           // HttpResponseMessage response = await CallAPI(client => client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/account/SignIn", user));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await CallAPI(client => client.PostAsync("api/AgentCollection", new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")));


            bool result = false;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                result = await response.Content.read.ReadAsAsync<bool>();                    
            }

            return result;
        }
```

In the above piece of code 
  I got an error at `PostAsJsonAsync`. Based on this  [Article](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-use-HttpClient-to-b9289836)
  I changed `client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/account/SignIn", user);` to `client.PostAsync("api/AgentCollection", new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))`

now I am getting following error for ReadAsAsync().
  what should be the replacement for `result = await response.Content.read.ReadAsAsync<bool>();`